# Fiware keyrock installation

Tags: fiware

I have trouble installing and setting up keyrock development environment.
We have set up virtualenv and installed requirements according to [this guide](https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-idm/wiki/Installation-guide).
Everything seemed to be ok, but none of the fabric commands are working. Every time we try to run a fab command within cloned idm directory, this error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/.virtualenvs/idm_tools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 658, in main docstring, callables, default = load_fabfile(fabfile)
File "/root/.virtualenvs/idm_tools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 165, in load_fabfile imported = importer(os.path.splitext(fabfile)[0])
File "/root/idm/fabfile.py", line 17, in <module> from deployment import keystone
File "/root/idm/deployment/keystone.py", line 25, in <module> from keystoneclient.v3 import client
File "/root/.virtualenvs/idm_tools/src/fiwareclient/keystoneclient/__init__.py", line 34, in <module> from keystoneclient import client
File "/root/.virtualenvs/idm_tools/src/fiwareclient/keystoneclient/client.py", line 13, in <module> from keystoneclient import discover
File "/root/.virtualenvs/idm_tools/src/fiwareclient/keystoneclient/discover.py", line 22, in <module> from keystoneclient.v2_0 import client as v2_client
File "/root/.virtualenvs/idm_tools/src/fiwareclient/keystoneclient/v2_0/__init__.py", line 1, in <module> from keystoneclient.v2_0.client import Client  # noqa
File "/root/.virtualenvs/idm_tools/src/fiwareclient/keystoneclient/v2_0/client.py", line 23, in <module> from keystoneclient.v2_0 import ec2
File "/root/.virtualenvs/idm_tools/src/fiwareclient/keystoneclient/v2_0/ec2.py", line 16, in <module> from keystoneclient import base
File "/root/.virtualenvs/idm_tools/src/fiwareclient/keystoneclient/base.py", line 31, in <module> from keystoneclient.openstack.common.apiclient import base
File "/root/.virtualenvs/idm_tools/src/fiwareclient/keystoneclient/openstack/common/apiclient/base.py", line 29, in <module> from oslo.utils import strutils
ImportError: No module named oslo.utils
```

As far as I can see, oslo.utils is installed in /root/.virtualenvs/idm_tools/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Answer (score 0):

A fix was committed on KeyRock's Github account fixing the package's namespace.

If you pull changes from github and run:

> sudo python tools/install_venv.py

it should fix it.

You can check out the github issue [here](https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-idm/issues/3)